# Not able to do USB Tethering on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, tethering

I was trying to USB tether my Samsung Galaxy S7 to use home wifi on my desktop which has Ubuntu 16.04. When I turn 'USB tethering' on, I was not able to connect to any device.

Answer (score 5):

I found this post which was helpful https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359171

```
ifconfig -a
```

lists the network interfaces. Mine was listed as "enp0s20f0u2".

Then I did `sudo apt-get install macchanger`. There was a prompt for which I selected "No".

Then I ran `sudo macchanger -b -a enp0s20f0u2`. After this the output was:

```
 Ignoring --bia option that can only be used with --random
 Current MAC:   00:00:00:00:00:00 (XEROX CORPORATION)
 Permanent MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (XEROX CORPORATION)
 New MAC:       00:11:a5:16:14:29 (Fortuna Electronic Corp.)
```

This seemed to solve the issue

Comment: @cipricus did you use sudo?

Comment: yes. but the prolem was with my phone in fact, now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Check for all available networks interfaces

```
ifconfig -a
```

Then for respective network interface use

```
ifconfig *name of network interface* up
```

Comment: Yes, one should try your answer before trying mine. Thanks.